# Finding all possible paths between all vertices of a graph

Tags: path, wolfram-mathematica

I have a directed graph with 13 vertices and would like to examine all possible simple paths of all lengths (max=12). I tried the FindPath[Graph,Vertex1,Vertex2,12,All] formula, but had to enter this function 13*12 times due to the fact that I don’t know how to extract the paths in a quicker and simpler way. Is there a way to extract all the paths (from every vertex to every other vertex) with just one formula instead of 156 formulas?
I also have access to the Adjacency-Matrix, which might hint to another possible way, but I don’t know how to extract paths from the adjacency Matrix.
I know that there have been a lot of questions about how to find all possible paths between two vertices, but I need a bigger image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing is that you don't know the primitives for mapping a function on a two-dimensional array  or triangle.  Lookup `Map`, `Outer`, `Table`, `Scan`, `MapThread`, etc. in Mathematica Documentation.

One way to do it is (adapted to your case) :

```
Flatten[ Table[ Table[ 
  FindPath[ mygraph, vertexlist[[i]],  vertexlist[[j]], 12, All ],
    {j,i+1, Length[vertexlist] }], {i, 1, Length[vertexlist]-1 }], 1]
```

assuming you put in vertexlist the identifications of your vertices. If these are just integers from 1 to 13, you can just put i in place of vertexlist[[i]] etc.

You will get n*(n-1)/2 lists of paths between two different vertices, sorted by starting vertex. If your graph is oriented, you might want the whole n*(n-1) instead. Simple modifications of the code above will give you that.